# Can't make websocket connection in fresh 8.1 install

Tags: windows-8

Getting the following error

```
WebSocket Error: Network Error 12029, A connection with the server could not be established.
```

whenever I try to connect to a socket server on a PC with a fresh Windows install.

I've turned all firewalls off.

Is there something else in windows I can check?

Error 12029 seems like a generic error, is there any way to debug these types of websocket errors?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean fresh as in "fresh from the store", mine came with this bloatware called "Superfish" which was blocking all incoming websocket messages.